# Makefile : using environment variable or cmd line argument

Tags: build, makefile

I have a requirement where i need to set a variable in the makefile depending upon :

1. If it is passed as an argument to the makefile
2. If it is set as an environment variable.

The name of the variable is same if set as env variable or passed as argument.
Priority is the one passed as argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make already provides this behavior, built in.  When make starts all environment variables are imported as make variables.  And any variable assignment set on the command line overrides all other settings of the variable, including both in the environment and in the makefile.

Can you be more clear about what you want, that is not the same as the default behavior?

Comment: The default behavior was what i was looking for.